# How to set success url as the previous page after updating an instance in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to redirect the user to the previous page after they have updated an instance in the Model `Class`. So, here is the view for the update:

```
class ClassStatusDetailView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Class
    template_name = "agents/class_status_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "class"
    fields = ['status']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("agents:agent-list")
```

Right now, as you can see, the `get_success_url` is set to "agents:agent-list", which is not the previous page. Also, here is the template for the update view in case you need it:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}

{% block content %}

<div class="max-w-lg mx-auto">
    <a class="hover:text-blue-500" href="#">Something</a>
    <div class="py-5 border-t border-gray-200">
        <h1 class="text-4xl text-gray-800">{{ class.student }}</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post" class="mt-5">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type='submit' class="w-full text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">
            Update
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

However, there is a catch. The previous page I want to return to is a function view with a primary key. So, not only do I have to go back to this function view, but I also have to go to the correct primary key. Please tell me if you guys need any other information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user successfully **update** their data then he/she **redirect** to `class_list.html` page..

**urls.py**(I assume):

```
 path('class_list/<int:pk>/', class_list,name = 'class_list'),
 path('edit_class/<int:pk>/', ClassStatusDetailView.as_view(),name = 'edit_class')
```

**models.py**:

```
    class ClassStatusDetailView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
            model = Class
            template_name = "agents/class_status_detail.html"
            context_object_name = "class"
            fields = ['status']
        
            def get_success_url(self):
                agent_id = self.object.teacher.id
                return reverse_lazy('class_list', kwargs={'pk': agent_id})
```

Use [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question so that it includes the view I want the user to return to. As you can see, the "previous page" is a function list view that has a primary key. I hope you can take a look.

Comment: @codebuilder See my updated answer. Plz tell me this works or not. If not work this then put `models.py` in your **question**.